# Bind to a method in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, xaml

How do you bind to an objects method in this scenario in WPF?

```cs
public class RootObject
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public ObservableCollection<ChildObject> GetChildren() {...}
}

public class ChildObject
{
    public string Name { get; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="some list of RootObjects">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:RootObject}" 
                                  ItemsSource="???">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:ChildObject}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Here I want to bind to the `GetChildren` method on each `RootObject` of the tree.

**EDIT** Binding to an `ObjectDataProvider` doesn't seem to work because I'm binding to a list of items, and the `ObjectDataProvider` needs either a static method, or it creates it's own instance and uses that.

For example, using Matt's answer I get:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 33 : ObjectDataProvider cannot create object; Type='RootObject'; Error='Wrong parameters for constructor.'
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 34 : ObjectDataProvider: Failure trying to invoke method on type; Method='GetChildren'; Type='RootObject'; Error='The specified member cannot be invoked on target.' TargetException:'System.Reflection.TargetException: Non-static method requires a target.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. ObjectDataProvider does have an ObjectInstance property (to call its method on a specific instance) but I don't think it's a dependency property, so you can't bind it (AFAIK).

Comment: Yeah I tried to bind to ObjectInstance and found out it's not a dependency property.

Comment: I'll leave my answer there anyway, both to give your update some context and to help someone else who finds this question with a similar enough problem.

Comment: Do you actually need to bind to ObjectInstance? (Will it change) Assuming so you could instead create your own change-event handling and update the ObjectDataProvider in code...

Comment: Just updated my answer with some source code, a year after the fact.

Answer (score 73):

Another approach that might work for you is to create a custom [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613620.aspx) that takes a method name as a parameter, so that it would be used like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding 
    Converter={StaticResource MethodToValueConverter},
    ConverterParameter='GetChildren'}"
```

This converter would find and invoke the method using reflection.  This requires the method to not have any arguments.

Here's an example of such a converter's source:

```c#
public sealed class MethodToValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var methodName = parameter as string;
        if (value==null || methodName==null)
            return value;
        var methodInfo = value.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, new Type[0]);
        if (methodInfo==null)
            return value;
        return methodInfo.Invoke(value, new object[0]);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("MethodToValueConverter can only be used for one way conversion.");
    }
}
```

And a corresponding unit test:

```c#
[Test]
public void Convert()
{
    var converter = new MethodToValueConverter();
    Assert.AreEqual("1234", converter.Convert(1234, typeof(string), "ToString", null));
    Assert.AreEqual("ABCD", converter.Convert(" ABCD ", typeof(string), "Trim", null));

    Assert.IsNull(converter.Convert(null, typeof(string), "ToString", null));

    Assert.AreEqual("Pineapple", converter.Convert("Pineapple", typeof(string), "InvalidMethodName", null));
}
```

Note that this converter does not enforce the `targetType` parameter.

Comment: Hmmm,...seems like a hack but I'm starting to think this might be the only way.  It's damn sure gonna be the easiest!

Comment: This is useful, but won't capture extension methods, including all Linq. In practice, these would be most useful, like e.g. binding to `Last()` in a sequence.

Answer (score 28):

Not sure how well it will work in your scenario, but you can use the [`MethodName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.methodname.aspx) property on `ObjectDataProvider` to have it call a specific method (with specific parameters of you `MethodParameters` property) to retrieve its data.

Here's a snippet taken directly from the MSDN page:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:TemperatureScale}"
        MethodName="ConvertTemp" x:Key="convertTemp">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <system:Double>0</system:Double>
            <local:TempType>Celsius</local:TempType>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

So that's an `ObjectDataProvider` that's calling a `ConvertTemp` method on an instance of a `TemperatureScale` class, passing two parameters (`0` and `TempType.Celsius`).

Answer (score 13):

Do you have to bind to the method?

Can you bind to a property who's getter is the method?

```
public ObservableCollection<ChildObject> Children
{
   get
   {
      return GetChildren();
   }
}
```

Comment: I take Cameron's comment to mean that he is binding to a type that he can not add a property to.

Comment: You should avoid binding to properties that call methods esp if the method could potentially be long running. Having such methods it properties is not good design as a consumer of code expects a property to only access a local variable.

Comment: @markmnl so what is the point of binding directly to function? So OP's question does not make any sense on your case?

Answer (score 6):

Unless you can add a property to call the method (or create a wrapper class that adds that property) the only way I know of is using a ValueConverter.

Answer (score 3):

ObjectDataProvider also has an ObjectInstance property that can be used instead of ObjectType

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.ComponentModel` to define properties for a type dynamically (they're not part of the compiled metadata).  I used this approach in WPF to enable binding to a type that stored its values in fields, as binding to fields is not possible.

The [`ICustomTypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) and [`TypeDescriptionProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider.aspx) types might allow you to achieve what you want.  According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163804.aspx):

> `TypeDescriptionProvider` allows you to write a separate class that implements `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and then to register this class as the provider of descriptions for other types.

I haven't tried this approach myself, but I hope it's helpful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

To bind to an object's method in your WPF scenario, you can bind to a property that returns a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Same as Drew Noakes's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/844946/12285424), but with an ability to use extension methods.

```cs
public sealed class MethodToValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var methodName = parameter as string;
        if (value == null || methodName == null)
            return value;
        var methodInfo = value.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, Type.EmptyTypes);
        if (methodInfo == null)
        {
            methodInfo = GetExtensionMethod(value.GetType(), methodName);
            if (methodInfo == null) return value;
            return methodInfo.Invoke(null, new[] { value });
        }
        return methodInfo.Invoke(value, Array.Empty<object>());
    }

    static MethodInfo? GetExtensionMethod(Type extendedType, string methodName)
    {
        var method = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(type => !type.IsGenericType && !type.IsNested)
            .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic), (_, method) => method)
            .Where(m => m.IsDefined(typeof(ExtensionAttribute), false))
            .Where(m => m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == extendedType)
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == methodName);
        return method;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("MethodToValueConverter can only be used for one way conversion.");
    }
}
```