# How can I put a return string value in the Text property of a text block?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

Let's say I need to display the appliation version which is returned by a static method:

I don't know the syntax to called a static method or whether it is possible to do so. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind to a method in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502250/bind-to-a-method-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dependency property and then get the version number of your assebly with this C# code.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());
```