# XAML access method in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bind to a method in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502250/bind-to-a-method-in-wpf)

Is there a simple way to access a method form my code behind in XAML?

I've seen solutions that use ObjectDataProvider, but from my understanding they create a new instace of the given type and call the method of this object. This would be of no use for me, as I need to call the actual code of my class (datacontext is important for methods!)…

`Route.xaml.cs: public string GetDifficultyName(int id);`

`Route.xaml: Displays a list of routes`

Every route has a property "DiffId", that has to be passed to the method above and the result has to be set as value to a textbox -> resolves the id to a human readable description.

Comment: Check [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502250/bind-to-a-method-in-wpf/844946#844946) that shows how to bind to a method within WPF XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing this is exposing a `ValueConverter` instance as a resource in your `Window` (or `Control` or whatever) which has been initialized in your code-behind appropriately to call into the method(s) you require.

For example:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(string))]
public class RouteDifficultyNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private readonly IMyMethodProvider provider;

    public RouteDifficultyNameConverter(IMyMethodProvider provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return provider.GetDifficultyName((int)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

This is not a properly complete converter of course, but you get the idea.

And in your code-behind's constructor:

```
    this.Resources.Add("routeDifficultyConverter",
                       new RouteDifficultyNameConverter(this));
    this.InitializeComponent();
```