# Binding XmlDataProvider Source attribute to a static function in another form?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, xmldataprovider

I am trying to bind an XmlDataProvider with a Source attribute to a static function in another form.

Here's XmlDataProvider line -

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="Lang" Source="/lang/english.xml" XPath="Language/MainWindow"/>
```

I would like it's Source attribute to be binded to a static function called: "GetValue_UILanguage" in a form called: "Settings"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502250/bind-to-a-method-in-wpf/4452582#4452582) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502250/bind-to-a-method-in-wpf/844946#844946) for a converter that allows you to bind to methods.

You could probably modify it to be able to access static methods of any class as well.

**Edit:** Here's a modified converter that should find the method via reflection.

*(Note: You would be better off using a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) instead, as you do not actually bind any value.)*

```
public sealed class StaticMethodToValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            var methodPath = (parameter as string).Split('.');
            if (methodPath.Length < 2) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            string methodName = methodPath.Last();

            var fullClassPath = new List<string>(methodPath);
            fullClassPath.RemoveAt(methodPath.Length - 1);
            Type targetClass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(String.Join(".", fullClassPath));

            var methodInfo = targetClass.GetMethod(methodName, new Type[0]);
            if (methodInfo == null)
                return value;
            return methodInfo.Invoke(null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("MethodToValueConverter can only be used for one way conversion.");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Window.Resources>
    ...
    <local:StaticMethodToValueConverter x:Key="MethodToValueConverter"/>
    ...
</Window.Resources>

...

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MethodToValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=Test.App.GetEmps}">
...
```

The method in the App class:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static Employee[] GetEmps() {...}
    }
}
```

I tested this and it works, it is important to use the full class path though, `App.GetEmps` alone would not have worked.

Comment: if not from a static function, is it possible to take a value from static variable? how?

Comment: For that you can use `{x:Static namespace:SomeClass.StaticProperty}`

Comment: I have already tried to do that but when i start the program it gives me a bug report.
I have added: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Visual_Command_Line" as namespace.
And my code:
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Lang" Source="{x:Static local:Settings.fullPath}" XPath="Language/MainWindow"/>
</Window.Resources>

Comment: What is the error you get? Is the `Settings` class in the namespace you specified?

Comment: the "Settings" class is in the namespace i specified.. I don't get any error, right when I start the program i get a message saying my program has stopped working with 3 buttons: "check online for a solution", "close the program", "debug the program" - the usual windows don't send / send bug report

Comment: Why is that? Aren't you using any debugger?

Comment: Obvious follow up question: Whyyyyy? I mean seriously, how can you even get anything done without a debugger? And i can't help you either if all i know is that your program, for which i don't have any code, crashed.

Comment: i tried using the debugger in c# it gives me the following message: "XamlParseException occurred" : "Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Source' to object of type 'System.Uri'. Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Uri'.  Error at object 'Lang' in markup file 'Visual_Command_Line;component/mainwindow.xaml'." what should i do?

Comment: well, I guess i should have used C# debugger - it said everything i need to do. xD. thanks!