# How can I bind one property to another property, offset by a specific amount?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-controls, pixelsense

I'm trying to bind two points of a line to two Ellipses, which are inside ScatterViewItems.
At the moment, I'm able to bind to ActualCenter.X and .Y for the ScatterViewItem, which works, but because the ellipse is not the only element in that ScatterViewItem (there is also a label), it's off-center, such that the line's endpoints are not the center of the ellipse.

Ellipse doesn't have an ActualCenter property.

I wanted to know whether I'm able to offset a property binding by a fixed amount, or whether there is some other kind of binding I can use such that I can work out the correct ellipse center in the container class (for the ellipse, label and scatterviewitem), and return that as the source of the binding.

Below is the code where I am setting the binding. `this.avatar` refers to a `Line` shape. `node_one` and `node_two` are the container objects, which contain a `ScatterViewItem`. The `Node` class also contains the `Ellipse`, the centre for which I would essentially like as the source, but I'm happy with a simple offset of the current source.

```
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.avatar, Line.X1Property, new Binding
        {
            Source = node_one.getScatterViewItem(),
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.X")
        });
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.avatar, Line.Y1Property, new Binding
        {
            Source = node_one.GetNodeCenterY(),
            Path = new PropertyPath("GetNodeCenterY()")
        });

        // Bind line.(X2,Y2) to destination.ActualCenter  
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.avatar, Line.X2Property, new Binding
        {
            Source = node_two.getScatterViewItem(),
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.X")
        });
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.avatar, Line.Y2Property, new Binding
        {
            Source = node_two.GetNodeCenterY(),
            Path = new PropertyPath("GetNodeCenterY()")
        });
```

I attempted to set to the `Source` as `node_one` and `Path` as `new PropertyPath("getOffsetCenter()")` which returns a double, but it didn't work. It didn't complain, but it didn't work :) Any tips are appreciated :)

---

Edit, trying to use IValueConverter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Double), typeof(Double))]
public class OffsetValues : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        Double y = (Double)value;
        Double offset = (Double)parameter;
        return y + offset;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Double dblValue = (Double)value;
        Double offset = (Double)parameter;
        Double resultDblValue = dblValue - offset;
        return resultDblValue;
    }
}
```

The above was added as a new class, but how would I attach it to the source of my binding - the example at MSDN has a XAML based implementation but mine is all programmatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write some ValueConverter in the code behind for that.

For further information look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fischermaen. The implementation on the MSDN site is XAML based - what would be the equivalent in C#? I also tried creating a separate class with a property "offsetValue", where the constructor initialises the offsetValue with parameters provided. I used the instance of this class as Source, and "offsetValue" as the Path, but didn't work; I thought any object could be used as Source, but only DependencyProperties as targets?

Comment: nvm, I see it's meant to go as the "Converter=" value for the inline Binding.

Comment: @timberwo7ves: You can add the value converter in source behind too. The `Binding` class has a Converter property as well. Almost everything can be set in Xaml or code behind as well.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to set a binding to a method call, not a property. Bindings can only reference Properties, since the dependency property the binding is set on is meant to point to the location of a property, not to a method call.

I have seen people [use a Converter to convert a Method to a Property value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/844946/302677), however have not used it myself.

As a side note, I got tired of always writing converters to offset my bindings by a set amount, so created my own [Math Converter](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/the-math-converter/) to do this. To use it, just set the `ConverterParameter` to a mathematical equation with `@VALUE` substituting for the bound value, such as `(@VALUE / 2) + 20`. If you want it to use more than one bound value, just change it to a `MultiConverter`

Comment: Thanks Rachel. Having succeeded with offsetting the value, I've realised I've been going about the problem the wrong way - now when the ScatterViewItem is oriented at 180 deg the offset is in the wrong direction; rather I should have focused on ensuring the Ellipse is at the centre of the ScatterViewItem, which is a lot easier!

Answer (score 1):

First create a value converter:

```cs
    [ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
    public sealed class OffsetValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var dblValue = (double)value;
            var offset = parameter is string pstr ? double.Parse(pstr) : (double) parameter;
            return dblValue + offset;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var dblValue = (double)value;
            var offset = (double)parameter;
            return dblValue - offset;
        }
    }
```

Next, create an instance in your `UserControl` and reference it as a `Converter` in your `Binding` with a `ConverterParameter`:

```xml
<ParentControl x:Name="ParentName">
    <ParentControl.Resources>
        <local:OffsetValueConverter x:Key="Offset" />
    </ParentControl.Resources>
    <ParentControl.Content>
        <ChildControl Height="{Binding 
            ElementName=ParentName,
            Path=Height,
            Converter={StaticResource Offset},
            ConverterParameter=-16}" />
    </ParentControl.Content>
</ParentControl>
```