# How do I data bind the result of a view-model method to a TextBox property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, methods, markup-extensions

In my view-model and model I have a method with the signature of `bool IsPropertyReadOnly(string propertyName)`. This method determines if the currently logged in user can edit a propery value. A few users will be able to edit property values and most of the others will have read-only access.

Instead of creating a property to return the read-only status of each of the model's properties, I want to bind the result of the `IsPropertyReadOny` to the `TextBox.IsReadOnly` property.

This is how I envision the syntax:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         IsReadOnly="{Binding MethodName=IsPropertyReadOnly MethodParameter=Address}"
/>
```

The `DataContext` contains the view-model, so basically I need to bind `IsReadOnly` to the result of the call `((Class)this.DataContext).IsPropertyReadOnly("Address")`

There is much documentation in using an `ObjectDataProvider`, but the object data provider creates a new object instance which is not what I want. Moreover, to use an existing instance I must make the assignment in code-behind. Again, not what I want to do.

From my research, it seems that a solution that inherits from `Binding` or `MarkupExtension` is better suited to my needs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here might be an answer for your question (the last answer that uses converter):
[Bind to a method in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502250/bind-to-a-method-in-wpf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a converter. Here is example. Suppose you have a simple ViewModel class:

```c#
class ViewModel
{
    public string Read
    { get; set; }

    public string ReadWrite
    { get; set; }

    public bool IsPropertyReadOnly(string propertyName)
    {
        return propertyName != "ReadWrite";
    }
}
```

To solve your problem you need to write a converter, such as:

```c#
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var vm = value as ViewModel;
        var functionName = (string)parameter;

        var result = vm.IsPropertyReadOnly(functionName);
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This method should never be called");
    }
}
```

And that's all; now you can use this converter in XAML, like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <temp:Converter x:Key="ReadOnlyMethodConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Read, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=.,
        Converter={StaticResource ReadOnlyMethodConverter}, ConverterParameter=Read}"
    />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ReadWrite, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=.,
        Converter={StaticResource ReadOnlyMethodConverter}, ConverterParameter=ReadWrite}"
    />
</StackPanel>
```

And in code-behind we just create ViewModel and set it as DataContext:

```c#
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though I used a suggestion by H.B. in another answer, I accepted and voted on this answer because I think it fully answers the question on binding to a method with parameters on the view model.

Comment: I think there were too many answers in the previous comment. :O)

Answer (score 4):

> Moreover, to use an existing instance I must make the assignment in code-behind. Again, not what I want to do.

That is not true, your choices however will be limited.

---

How about indexers?

```cs
private readonly Dictionary<string, bool> _PropertyReadOnlyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
public Dictionary<string, bool> PropertyReadOnlyDictionary { get { return _PropertyReadOnlyDictionary; } }
```

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}"
        IsReadOnly="{Binding PropertyReadOnlyDictionary[Address]}" />
```

---

You could of course wrap your method in a new class which allows access via an indexer as well if you don't want to use a dictionary.

```cs
private readonly PropertyIsReadOnlyResolver _PropertyIsReadOnlyResolver = new PropertyIsReadOnlyResolver();
public PropertyIsReadOnlyResolver PropertyIsReadOnlyResolver { get { return _PropertyIsReadOnlyResolver; } }
```

```cs
public class PropertyIsReadOnlyResolver
{
    public bool this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            return IsPropertyReadOnly(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public bool IsPropertyReadOnly(string propertyName)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}"
        IsReadOnly="{Binding PropertyIsReadOnlyResolver[Address]}" />
```

Comment: Interesting, we did use an indexer at first. I decided against it because we need to use `IDataErrorInfo`. I like the first indexer with the dictionary because it fits into our implementation better.

Comment: We used the PropertyReadOnlyDictionary implementation and it integrated perfectly with our design. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by using an `ObjectDataProvider` to execute the method and then bind the attached property to the provider's return value.

First you'll need to configure the provider as a resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="readOnlyProvider" ...>
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      ...
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
  </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then use the provider as the source of your attached property binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PoolNum, Mode=OneWay}" Windows:AttachedProperties.IsReadOnlyOn="{Binding Source={StaticResource readOnlyProvider}}" />
```

The tricky part of this process will be "passing" a value to the `ObjectDataProviders.MethodParameters`. This can be done in XAML and there are several resources out there to show you how it's done; here's one to get started: http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2010/02/23/bind-objectdataprovider-method-parameters-in-wpf.aspx

**UPDATE**

Per your comment, here are two ways the `ObjectDataProvider` can execute the method on your view's `DataContext` without creating a new object.

First, make your view model method static and use the `ObjectType` property:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="readOnlyProvider"
  ObjectType="{x:local MyDataContext}"
  MethodName="IsPropertyReadOnly">
  ...
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Or, set the `ObjectInstance` of the provider to the view's `DataContext` when the view loads:

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
  public MyWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var readOnlyProvider = this.Resources["readOnlyProvider"] as ObjectDataProvider;
    readOnlyProvider.ObjectInstance = this.DataContext;
  }
}
```

There is no way to bind to methods in XAML and the only workarounds I know of make use of the `ObjectDataProvider`.

Comment: But, I do not want the `ObjectDataProvider` creating a new object. It would be nice if I can set the provider's object.