# binding to the ToString() method in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

Is there any easy way to bind to the ToString() method in a DataTemplate? I would expect the Text property of a TextBlock to use ToString() by default for its Text property, but that does not happen. So any easy way to do this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToString()}"/>
<DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use `Text="{Binding}"`. The `ToString()` method is invoked implicitly.

Comment: This also works well when binding to an enum where you want to display the `Enum.ToString()`.

Comment: how do you pass parmaeter to the `ToString()`method ? (for instance, for formatting a `TimeSpan`)

Comment: @Pac0 Check the StringFormat parameter

Comment: Also works with `Text="{x:Bind}"`

Answer (score 7):

you can use a Converter. like this:

```
public class PropertyValueStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.  with a slight edit.

return value != null ? value.ToString() : string.Empty;

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you cant bind control to method but you can circumvent to do that look:

```
public string GetText()
{
    return "I am happy";
}

public string MyText
{
    get { return GetText(); }
}
```

Now in XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
<DataTemplate>
```

be careful MyText property must be in the context of the window.

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to add a string property, for that specific ToString() method, to the object you are binding to.

Answer (score 0):

WPF does not support binding to methods directly, but you could use custom IValueConverter, ObjectDataProvider or any other approach as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502250/bind-to-a-method-in-wpf).