# how to bind dynamic json into treeview wpf

Tags: json, wpf, treeview

I get JSON as follow:

```
explain format = json select...
```

Text is different depending on the type of operator select. How to bind dynamic JSON in treeView or maybe UML in wpf.
Thx for advice

Answer (score 43):

You can do this with the [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) framework.  Json.NET has a static method [`JToken.Parse()`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse.htm) (which is similar in purpose to [`XDocument.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and can turn a valid JSON string into a hierarchy of [`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) objects.  This hierarchy can be bound into a [WPF TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control using [`DataTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to format data from all possible subclasses of `JToken` and iterate through their children.

The concrete Json.NET `JToken` classes for which templates are required are:

- [`JValue`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm)
- [`JObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)
- [`JArray`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm)
- [`JProperty`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm)
- [`JConstructor`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JConstructor.htm)
- [`JRaw`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JRaw.htm)

In order to bind a hierarchy of these classes into a tree, you first need a [converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502250/bind-to-a-method-in-wpf/844946#844946) to convert the [`JToken.Children()`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Children.htm) method into a property:

```
// Respectfully adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502250/bind-to-a-method-in-wpf/844946#844946

public sealed class MethodToValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var methodName = parameter as string;
        if (value == null || methodName == null)
            return null;
        var methodInfo = value.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, new Type[0]);
        if (methodInfo == null)
            return null;
        return methodInfo.Invoke(value, new object[0]);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(GetType().Name + " can only be used for one way conversion.");
    }
}
```

Having done this, an extremely simple XAML markup that can display this hierarchy in a tree is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfJsonTreeViewNew.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:w="clr-namespace:WpfJsonTreeViewNew"
    xmlns:json ="clr-namespace:Newtonsoft.Json;assembly=Newtonsoft.Json"
    xmlns:jlinq ="clr-namespace:Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;assembly=Newtonsoft.Json"
    Title="Window1" Height="1000" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <w:MethodToValueConverter x:Key="MethodToValueConverter"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type jlinq:JArray}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MethodToValueConverter}, ConverterParameter='Children'}">
            <TextBlock Text="Array">
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type jlinq:JProperty}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MethodToValueConverter}, ConverterParameter='Children'}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Property name: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>            
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type jlinq:JObject}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MethodToValueConverter}, ConverterParameter='Children'}">
            <TextBlock Text="Object">
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>            
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type jlinq:JConstructor}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MethodToValueConverter}, ConverterParameter='Children'}">
            <TextBlock Text="Constructor">
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>            
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type jlinq:JRaw}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MethodToValueConverter}, ConverterParameter='Children'}">
            <TextBlock Text="Raw">
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>            
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type jlinq:JValue}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Value: "/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Margin="3" Name="treeView1">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then, when your user selects JSON data to view, you can do:

```
        var token = JToken.Parse(jsonString);

        var children = new List<JToken>();
        if (token != null)
        {
            children.Add(token);
        }

        treeView1.ItemsSource = null;
        treeView1.Items.Clear();
        treeView1.ItemsSource = children;
```

And the result looks like:

[image]

For the [sample JSON](http://adobe.github.io/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html):

```
{
    ""id"": ""0001"",
    ""type"": ""donut"",
    ""name"": ""Cake"",
    ""ppu"": 0.55,
    ""batters"":
        {
            ""batter"":
                [
                    { ""id"": ""1001"", ""type"": ""Regular"" },
                    { ""id"": ""1002"", ""type"": ""Chocolate"" },
                    { ""id"": ""1003"", ""type"": ""Blueberry"" },
                    { ""id"": ""1004"", ""type"": ""Devil's Food"" }
                ]
        },
    ""topping"":
        [
            { ""id"": ""5001"", ""type"": ""None"" },
            { ""id"": ""5002"", ""type"": ""Glazed"" },
            { ""id"": ""5005"", ""type"": ""Sugar"" },
            { ""id"": ""5007"", ""type"": ""Powdered Sugar"" },
            { ""id"": ""5006"", ""type"": ""Chocolate with Sprinkles"" },
            { ""id"": ""5003"", ""type"": ""Chocolate"" },
            { ""id"": ""5004"", ""type"": ""Maple"" }
        ]
}
```

Of course, the user interface could be made more beautiful, e.g. by placing the value for `JProperty` tokens with only a single `JValue` child on the same row.  However, this should give you an idea of how to do the binding.

This approach binds the JSON to the tree directly.  If you are looking for full editing functionality including adding, removing and renaming nodes, you may want to switch to a ["Model-View-ViewModel" methodology](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) in which the `JToken` hierarchy becomes the model and a lightweight view model handles modifications and notifications.

Comment: Happened to have code relevant to answer this to hand, so I did so, despite the age of the question.

Answer (score 37):

Based on dbc's answer above I went ahead and created a WPF JSON Viewer user control that should be easily integratable into any WPF project

[image: Imgur]

https://bitbucket.org/rasmuszimmer/wpf-jsonviewer-usercontrol

The project is a wpf solution demonstrating its use.

Go ahead and do with it whatever you want!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply install the nuGet Package JSONTreeView and call the function:

```
treeView.ProcessJson(string json);
```

This would be the result:

[image]