# how to bind json string to Tree view control in ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, treeview

I am building a web application that will accept the JSON string as input on left hand side of page (text box), on clicking on button on top, I need to format the JSON string & also bind the TREE VIEW Control on right hand side.

I am using NewtonSoft.JSON to convert the string to JSON.

But need some guidance to build the Tree view control using the JSON string. Is there any way? Please suggest

Comment: Still interested in an answer?

Comment: Yes please. as of now using NewSoft, am displaying the text in rich text box.

Comment: When I wrote that comment I somehow thought you were using WPF not ASP.NET.  For a WPF answer, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812357/how-to-bind-dynamic-json-into-treeview-wpf/28097883#28097883