# How to recursively populate a TreeView with JSON data

Tags: c#, json, winforms, treeview, parent-child

I have a winforms treeview, I can read data automatically, (a node that is equal to key, and a node inside that is equal to value), but when reading object type, the values inside it are not going to be child of object node (key of object), (maybe I couldnt explain well, here is a screenshot and my methods.)

layer0 needs to be inside textures and scale needs to be inside display

[image: layer0 needs to be inside textures and scale needs to be inside display]

My Json:

```
{
"parent": "builtin/generated",
"textures": {
    "layer0": "mm:items/iron_dust"
},
"display": {       
        "scale": [ 1.7, 1.7, 1.7 ]
 }
}
```

My method to auto detect(not all mine actually)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        getAllProperties(obj);
    }

    void getAllProperties(JToken children)
    {
        TreeNode mainNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
        mainNode.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
        foreach (JToken child in children.Children())
        {
            var property = child as JProperty;
            if (property != null)
            {
                if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.String)
                {
                    TreeNode keyNode = mainNode.Nodes.Add(property.Name);
                    keyNode.Nodes.Add(property.Value.ToString());
                }
                if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                {
                    JArray array = (JArray)property.Value;
                    TreeNode node = mainNode.Nodes.Add(property.Name);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
                    {
                        node.Nodes.Add(array[i].ToString());
                    }
                }
                if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                {
                    TreeNode topNode = mainNode.Nodes.Add(property.Name.ToString());
                    foreach (var item in property)
                    {
                        if (item.Type == JTokenType.String)
                        {
                             if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.String)
                {
                    TreeNode keyNode = topNode.Nodes.Add(property.Name);
                    keyNode.Nodes.Add(property.Value.ToString());
                }
                if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                {
                    JArray array = (JArray)property.Value;
                    TreeNode node = topNode.Nodes.Add(property.Name);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
                    {
                        node.Nodes.Add(array[i].ToString());
                    }
                }
                        }
                    }
                }


                    // Console.WriteLine(property.Name + ":" + property.Value);//print all of the values
                }
                getAllProperties(child);
            }
        }

    }
```

I tried to get parent, but it didnt have name and value properties :S.
Any help?
(Sorry for language mistakes)

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181298/how-to-do-recursive-descent-of-json-using-json-net) could help?

Comment: I will try when i can :) (I can't try it now) But.. i do not understand what walknode does here. Could you explain please?

Comment: `WalkNode` works like this: gets the node from argument, then iterates over every child of the node. It applies the `Action` function (which can be adding to the MainNode in your case) and then goes level deeper - calss `WalkNode` on the child. Basically, it recursively walks all the nodes in the JSON.

Comment: @JakubJankowski Thanks for detailed explanation :) But how can i add to MainNode? Since it is a TreeNode

Comment: You could copy the logic you have in your `foreach` loop (you access the mainNode of your TreeNode here, right?) and insert it in the `Action` function, referenced in `WalkNode`

Comment: @JakubJankowski Oh, thanks. You made my day :)

Comment: @JakubJankowski Do i need to change Action<JToken> to Action<JObject> ?

Comment: Probably yes, but I can't be sure as I haven't tried to use your code anyway nor had to parse JSON this way myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124094/discussion-between-talha-talip-acikgoz-and-jakub-jankowski).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that, as you recursively descend the `JToken` hierarchy, you also need to recursively descend the `TreeNode` hierarchy you are creating, adding child nodes to the parent node just created, rather than the root node, along the lines of [Recursion, parsing xml file with attributes into treeview c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp/29021038#29021038).

Thus if you do:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
        {
            var root = JToken.Load(jsonReader);
            DisplayTreeView(root, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));
        }
    }

    private void DisplayTreeView(JToken root, string rootName)
    {
        treeView1.BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            var tNode = treeView1.Nodes[treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(rootName))];
            tNode.Tag = root;

            AddNode(root, tNode);

            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
        finally
        {
            treeView1.EndUpdate();
        }
    }

    private void AddNode(JToken token, TreeNode inTreeNode)
    {
        if (token == null)
            return;
        if (token is JValue)
        {
            var childNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(token.ToString()))];
            childNode.Tag = token;
        }
        else if (token is JObject)
        {
            var obj = (JObject)token;
            foreach (var property in obj.Properties())
            {
                var childNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(property.Name))];
                childNode.Tag = property;
                AddNode(property.Value, childNode);
            }
        }
        else if (token is JArray)
        {
            var array = (JArray)token;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
            {
                var childNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(i.ToString()))];
                childNode.Tag = array[i];
                AddNode(array[i], childNode);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} not implemented", token.Type)); // JConstructor, JRaw
        }
    }
```

You will get the following tree view structure:

[image]

Comment: Whoa! This what all i need. But i wonder something.                                                                         Does this work for booleans :                                                                                                      if (token is JBoolean) {var childNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(token.ToString()))];
            childNode.Tag = token;}

Comment: There's no such thing as `JBoolean`.  Booleans are stored in `JValue`.  The set of all concrete linq-to-JSON types is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812357/how-to-bind-dynamic-json-into-treeview-wpf/28097883#28097883).

Answer (score 10):

Here is my crack at it. The output is identical to Notepad++'s JSTool plug-in:
[image: TreeView showing JSON]

The code is structured as a TreeView extension:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestDLApp.Utilities.Extensions
{
    public static class ObjectToTreeView
    {
        private sealed class IndexContainer
        {
            private int _n;
            public int Inc() => _n++;
        }

        private static void FillTreeView(TreeNode node, JToken tok, Stack<IndexContainer> s)
        {
            if (tok.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                TreeNode n = node;
                if(tok.Parent != null)
                {
                    if(tok.Parent.Type == JTokenType.Property)
                    {
                        n = node.Nodes.Add($"{((JProperty)tok.Parent).Name} <{tok.Type.ToString()}>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        n = node.Nodes.Add($"[{s.Peek().Inc()}] <{tok.Type.ToString()}>");
                    }
                }
                s.Push(new IndexContainer());
                foreach (var p in tok.Children<JProperty>())
                {
                    FillTreeView(n, p.Value, s);
                }
                s.Pop();
            }
            else if (tok.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                TreeNode n = node;
                if(tok.Parent != null)
                {
                    if (tok.Parent.Type == JTokenType.Property)
                    {
                        n = node.Nodes.Add($"{((JProperty)tok.Parent).Name} <{tok.Type.ToString()}>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        n = node.Nodes.Add($"[{s.Peek().Inc()}] <{tok.Type.ToString()}>");
                    }
                }
                s.Push(new IndexContainer());
                foreach (var p in tok)
                {
                    FillTreeView(n, p, s);
                }
                s.Pop();
            }
            else
            {
                var name = string.Empty;
                var value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(((JValue)tok).Value);

                if (tok.Parent.Type == JTokenType.Property)
                {
                    name = $"{((JProperty)tok.Parent).Name} : {value}";
                }
                else
                {
                    name = $"[{s.Peek().Inc()}] : {value}";
                }

                node.Nodes.Add(name);
            }
        }

        public static void SetObjectAsJson<T>(this TreeView tv, T obj)
        {
            tv.BeginUpdate();
            try
            {
                tv.Nodes.Clear();

                var s = new Stack<IndexContainer>();
                s.Push(new IndexContainer());
                FillTreeView(tv.Nodes.Add("ROOT"), JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)), s);
                s.Pop();
            }
            finally
            {
                tv.EndUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it as so:

```
treeView1.SetObjectAsJson(new MyNeatObject());
```