# Best way to iterate through a JToken?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I want to parse JSON with an undefined structure (any possible correct JSON) with Newtonsoft.Json using C# in Visual Studio 2015.

First, I read and parse JSON into a JToken:

```
...
var jsonData = ReadTextFromFile(filename);
var root = JToken.Parse(jsonData);
...
```

Now, I need to iterate through the JToken to construct my own tree `JsonTree` consisting of `JsonTreeNode` with additional info about every node.

Here is my `JsonTreeNode` class:

```
public class JsonTreeNode
{
    public JsonTreeNode()
    { }

    public JsonTreeNode(string name, string value, bool isArray, List<JsonTreeNode> children, JsonTreeNode parent, SomeAdditionalInfo info)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        IsArray = isArray;
        Children = children;
        ParentTreeNode = parent;
        AdditionalInfo = info;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsArray { get; set; }
    public JsonTreeNode ParentTreeNode { get; set; }
    public List<JsonTreeNode> Children { get; set; }
    public SomeAdditionalInfo AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Function to convert:

```
private static void ParseJsonToNode(JToken jsonToken, JsonTreeNode treeNode){...}
```

I don't know how convert each JToken to SomethingElse, so that I can get the Name and Value.

Here is a JSON file which shows the problem:

```
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "age": 29
}
```

When I parse it through `foreach` or recursively, the JToken has:

```
JToken(name):
-Type: Property
-Name: name
-Value: (Has no value)
-Children: 1
    JToken(Jack)
    -Type: String
    -Name (Has no name)
    -Value: "Jack"
    -Children: 0
JToken(age)
-Type: Property
-Name: age
-Value: (Has no value)
-Children: 1
    JToken(29)
    -Type: Integer
    -Name (Has no name)
    -Value: 29
    -Children: 0
```

But I don't need two JTokens for one value. I don't know how to composite them in the best way!

Comment: Check whether it's a `JObject`, `JArray`, or other type.

Comment: @SLaks add example

Comment: You will have to manually deal with the fact that `JObject` values have an additional level of nesting not present in `JArray` members.  See (How to recursively populate a TreeView with JSON data)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/39675191/3744182] for an example of how it might be done.