# Model method binding not working in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

I am creating a UWP app using MVVM. In my xaml view, I have a ListView that is bound to an ObservableCollection, and Object_X is a model. Other properties of Object_X bound to my xaml view inside this list view are working properly. However, I have a button inside this List View, whose click event I want to be bound to a method I defined in my Object_X class, but when I compile my code, I am getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object error".

This is my xaml code. ObjectXCollection is a property in my view model. IsSelected and Value are properties of Object_X, and that binding is working perfectly. ExpandButtonHandler is also defined as a method in the Object_X class, but it is giving me the error. If I remove that click property, my code builds and runs fine. My model is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, that's why the property binding are working properly. Can someone suggest a solution, or can someone see the problem?

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectXCollection, Mode=TwoWay}">
         <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" IsThreeState="True">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                </CheckBox>
                <Button Content=">>>" Click="{Binding ExpandButtonHandler}"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind to a Method, nor can you assign a Binding to an EventHandler. You can only set DependencyProperties to a Binding object by default.

Usually if I want to trigger some ViewModel code based on a UI event, I will use an [AttachedCommandBehavior](https://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) which allows you to use bindings in a UI event handler.

The end result looks something like this :

```
<Button x:Name="ExpandButton" Content=">>>"
        local:CommandBehavior.Event="Click"
        local:CommandBehavior.Action="{Binding ExpandButtonHandler}" />
```

The alternate solution is to just use code-behind the model, and call the method on your DataContext manually. Not as ideal, but it is an option.

```
private void ExpandButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var vm = ExpandButton.DataContext as SomeViewModel;
    vm.ExpandButtonHandler();
}
```

Comment: The method I'm trying to bind to is not in my viewmodel, it is in my model. The listview is bound to my ObservableCollection in my ViewModel, but then with the data template, the DataType becomes my Object_X, and that is why my properties bound with the model work perfectly fine. I'm confused why I'm not able to bound to the methods, cause it should be using the same instance of my Object_X that it is using for my property bindings.

Comment: @user3079315 That's fine, the answer remains the same though. WPF Bindings cannot bind to Methods. They can only bind to Public Properties. There are some [workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/844946/302677), however I would still recommend using an `ICommand` and AttachedCommandBehavior over that.

Answer (score 1):

Classic `Binding` doesn't allow direct binding to methods, but the new compiled binding, `x:Bind` does. You can read [more about compiled data binding here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/06/01/compiled-data-binding.aspx).

```
<Button Click="{x:Bind ExpandButtonHandler}" Content=">>>" />
```

Comment: I tried  with x:Bind as well,  but I still get the same error. I also tried declaring the x:DataType explicitly, even though I know it infers the correct datatype cause my property binding are working fine, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @user3079315 What is the signature of the method ExpandButtonHandler?

Comment: public void ExpandButtonHandler()

Also, I'm using prism MVVM, so I don't have Object Sender etc