# WPF binding of two-level structured data without direct links

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I need represent two-level structured data by MVVM. If the data would be:

```
public class ParentEntity
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChildEntity> ChildsEntities { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ChildEntity>();
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ChildEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

then I would created binding with TreeView:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView">
    <TreeView.Resources>

        <!--Template for ParentEntity-->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ParentEntity}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildsEntities}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <!--Template for ChildEntity-->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ChildEntity}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>

ObservableCollection<ParentEntity> data = new ObservableCollection<ParentEntity>();
treeView.ItemsSource = data ;
```

But I have structure like this (from library):

```
public class ParentEntity
{
    public int UID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ChildEntity
{
    public int ParentUID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

How should it be handled? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered wrapping the entities in objects that provide the structure you describe in the first part of your question?

Comment: Yes, it was the first thought, but I don't sure it is the right approach.

Comment: You could try to use a IValueConverter to Invoke a method that returns the corresponding child objects to a parent see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/844946/4189791) but imo this is definitly not the "right" approach.

Comment: It means defining of extension method, that will find child entities by parentID (how? Filtering all entities?) and creating method converter... No, wrapping in my own objects really sounds better.

Comment: Yeah as I said i dont think it is the solution you should go for :D

Comment: Just write a couple of lines of code to take the class instances from the library and convert them into your first version of the classes, the ones with the ObservableCollection. Unless you've got a quite a large number of these things, that'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really recommending this, but I will solve the problem you have 
XAML

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="root">
        <StackPanel.DataContext>
            <vm:MainWindowViewModel></vm:MainWindowViewModel>
        </StackPanel.DataContext>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddRoot}">Add</Button>
        <TreeView Height="400">
            <TreeView.Resources >
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <vm:HierarchicalDataConverter x:Key="HierarchicalDataConverter"/>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ParentEntityTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:ParentEntity}" >
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HierarchicalDataConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                            <Binding Mode="OneTime"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.Items" ElementName="root" ></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.Items.Count" ElementName="root" ></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Name }"></TextBlock>
                        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.AddLeafe, ElementName=root}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">Add item</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate  x:Key="ChildEntityTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:ChildEntity}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.ItemsSource>
                <Binding Path="RootItems"/>
            </TreeView.ItemsSource>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector>
                <vm:ItemTemplateSelector>
                </vm:ItemTemplateSelector>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector>
        </TreeView>
    </StackPanel>
```

VM namespace

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; } =
            new ObservableCollection<object>(new List<object>(new List<object>
        {
            new ParentEntity { UID = 1, Name = "Groop1" },
            new ChildEntity { ParentUID = 1, Name = "Item1" },
            new ParentEntity { UID = 2, Name = "Groop2" },
            new ChildEntity { ParentUID = 2, Name = "Item1" },
            new ChildEntity { ParentUID = 2, Name = "Item2" },
            new ChildEntity { ParentUID = 2, Name = "Item3" }
        }));

        public CollectionView RootItems { get; }


        int count = 2;
        public DelegateCommand AddRoot { get; }

        public DelegateCommand<ParentEntity> AddLeafe { get; }
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            RootItems = new ListCollectionView(Items) { Filter = (item) => item is ParentEntity }; 

            AddRoot = new DelegateCommand(() =>
            {
                Items.Add(new ParentEntity { UID = ++count ,Name= "Group"+count});
            });

            AddLeafe = new DelegateCommand<ParentEntity>((pe) =>
            {
                Items.Add(new ChildEntity { ParentUID = pe.UID, Name = "Item" + count });
            });

        }

    }

    public class ParentEntity
    {
        public int UID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildEntity
    {
        public int ParentUID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate
            SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

            if (item is ParentEntity)
            {
                return element.FindResource("ParentEntityTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }
            if (item is ChildEntity)
            {
                return element.FindResource("ChildEntityTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class HierarchicalDataConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value[0] != null)
            {
                ParentEntity pe = value[0] as ParentEntity;
                var items = value[1] as IEnumerable<object>;

                return items.Where((item) => item is ChildEntity && (item as ChildEntity).ParentUID == pe.UID);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that it will recreate all the child nodes