# Possible way to reduce translation properties with MVVM in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm doing refactoring for our app. We currently have 2 languages supported, where the logic is sitting inside `TranslationService`, injected through DI container (using `Prism` if matters) into View models.

In order to bind the translation to the text property there is tons of properties in the view model, e.g.

```
public string SomeText => _translationService.GetTranslation("someText");

public string AnotherText => _translationService.GetTranslation("notherText");
```

And the binding is happening as usual

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Is there a way to reduce those properties? For example to bind the `Text` property to the `GetTranslation` method with a parameter?

I've seen [how to use ObjectDataProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502250/bind-to-a-method-in-wpf#answer-502262) but this doesn't really help me out, because the method parameters are hard-coded as per my understanding.

Comment: You can probably use `DynamicObject` to achieve your aim. It sounds like a poor design though, because you'd be circumventing one of the key safety features of C# (static typing).

Comment: If you used the text resources from .net directly, you'd simply write in xaml `<TextBlock Text={x:Static Resources.SomeText}/>` with no view model involvement at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may declare a helper class with a single indexer property like

```
public class Translation
{
    private readonly TranslationService translationService;

    public Translation(TranslationService service)
    {
        translationService = service;
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get { return translationService.GetTranslation(key); }
    }
}
```

which would be used as a single property in your view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Translation = new Translation(_translationService);
    }

    public Translation Translation { get; }
}
```

You would bind it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Translation[someText]}"/>
```